# What do + and - mean in the output of jobs command?

Tags: command-line, bash

I cannot find the answer anywhere. When i have several jobs that are in the background and i list them with jobs i get the following:

```
[1]   Stopped                 command1
[2]   Stopped                 command2
[3]-  Stopped                 command3
[4]+  Stopped                 command4
```

The plus sign is always on the last one, and the minus is on the second to last. What do these things mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They'll always be the latest and latest-minus-one running jobs.

Their only purpose, as far as I can tell, is to provide a shorthand for those two latest jobs so you can reference them as `fg -` instead of `fg %3`. This makes it fairly trivial to spin between two or three processes.

[TLDP seems to corroborate this (see Table 15-1. Job identifiers)](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html#JOBIDTABLE)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know about that shorthand. This way it does make sense.